# CakePHP check if there is a booked date

Tags: date, cakephp, compare, cakephp-2.0

I'm struggling with this since a week ago and it's driving me crazy.

I'm doing a website for doing surveys in a forest using CakePHP 2.x.

There is many places, and each place has different points. An user can choose one of those points and book a day for a survey, but there can be only one survey in a point each day.

The models are: `Place`, `Point`, `User`, `BookedSurvey`

The controllers are: `PlacesController`, `PointsController`, `UsersController`, `BookedSurveysControllers`

The tables (omitting some that are not necessaries for this question) are `places`, `points`, `users`, `booked_surveys`; and inside of `booked_surveys` you can find the fields `id (INT AUTO INCREMENT)`, `survey_date (datetime)`, `point_id (int)` and `user_id (int)`.

The views are: `add`, `edit`, `remove`, `index` for each one

When viewing a point, an user can select a date and press "Book survey". This is part of the view:

```
<h2>Book a date:</h2>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('BoostCake', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'div' => 'form-group',
        'label' => array(
            'class' => 'col col-md-1 control-label'
        ),
        'wrapInput' => 'col col-md-9',
        'class' => 'form-control'
    ),
    'class' => 'form-horizontal'
));
?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Point');

echo $this->Form->input('BookedSurvey.survey_date', array(
    'type'=>'date',
    'label' => '',
    'dateFormat' => 'YMD',
    'minYear' => date('Y'),
    'minMonth' => date('M'),
    'minDay' => date('D'),
    'div' => 'col col-md-9',
    'style' => 'margin: 15px 5px 5px 0px'
));

echo $this->Form->hidden('User.id', array(
    'value' => $user_id)
);
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->submit('Book survey', array(
        'div' => 'col col-md-9',
        'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg',
        'style' => 'margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px'
    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Then, the controler must search in `booked_survey` if the point has any survey for the same date. As each field should have only one survey per day, an error will be shown if there is any other survey in the same point for the same day.

And this is the problem: it never finds any coincidence. I Googled, tried all the different options, and still is not working. This is my seach in the `PointsController` (it's simplified, at the moment I'm trying to search any survey on the same date):

// Begin of comprobation

```
$booked_condition = $this->Point->BookedSurvey->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'DATE(BookedSurvey.survey_date)' => 'date()'
        )
    )
);

if ($booked_condition) {
    echo "Already booked"; 
}
```

// End of comprobation

To be honest, I don't know what is failing, but please, if somebody can help...

OK, solved:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $date = $this->request->data['BookedSurvey']['survey_date'];
    $formattedDate = CakeTime::format(
        "{$date['year']}-{$date['month']}-{$date['day']}",
        "%B %e, %Y"
    );
    print_r($formattedDate); //'Jul 23, 2014'

    $isBooked = $this->Point->BookedSurvey->find('count', array(
        // replace the date as you see fit, using Jul 23, 2014 as an example
        'conditions' => CakeTime::dayAsSql($formattedDate, 'survey_date')
    ));

    echo "status";
    print_r($isBooked);
    print_r(date('m'));
    print_r($this->request->data['BookedSurvey']['survey_date']);

    if($isBooked > 0) {
        echo "Already booked";
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add your solution as an actual answer and accept it later on. ps, you could also use **[`Model::deconstruct()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Model.html#_deconstruct)** to convert the date array into a date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, this is the solution to the problem:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$date = $this->request->data['BookedSurvey']['survey_date'];
$formattedDate = CakeTime::format(
    "{$date['year']}-{$date['month']}-{$date['day']}",
    "%B %e, %Y"
);
print_r($formattedDate); //'Jul 23, 2014'

$isBooked = $this->Point->BookedSurvey->find('count', array(
    // replace the date as you see fit, using Jul 23, 2014 as an example
    'conditions' => CakeTime::dayAsSql($formattedDate, 'survey_date')
));

echo "status";
print_r($isBooked);
print_r(date('m'));
print_r($this->request->data['BookedSurvey']['survey_date']);

if($isBooked > 0) {
    echo "Already booked";
}
```

}